# Permissions for using gwmi win32_ntlogevent instead of get-eventog?

Tags: powershell, wmi

The problem I have: get-eventlog works (I tested by doing "run as" on the PoSH ISE).  Get-WMIObject win32_ntlogevent does not. It's a perm issue of some sort.  Help please.

Background:

I've built a script that uses gwmi win32_ntlogevent to pull event logs.  (I chose it because it was an order of magnitude faster than either get-winevent or get-eventlog, even with filters).

However, I cannot reach some other servers in my environment.  So I had the Servers group add a credential to connect under, that has some sort of Log Reader right.  (not sure what they added)

Get-Eventlog:

```
$server = "myserver"
get-eventlog -ComputerName $server -logname "application"
```

(above returns results)

Get-WMIObject win32_ntlogevent does not. Neither with

```
Get-WmiObject win32_ntlogevent -ComputerName $server
```

or

```
$time = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime('2015/05/01 5:00:00am')
$EventQuery = @"
    select
      Logfile, RecordNumber, Timegenerated, TimeWritten, EventCode, EventType, Type, Category, CategoryString, SourceName, InsertionStrings, ComputerName, User, Message
    from Win32_NTlogEvent
    where timewritten >='$time'
    and LogFile = 'system'
"@ #this line must be un-recessed

gwmi -computername $server -Query $EventQuery
```

Instead, I get:

```
gwmi : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:10 char:1
+ gwmi -computername "myserver" -Query $EventQuery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Remote WMI Management](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enablewmi.aspx) might not be enabled. Since you don't have access to the servers, it's hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: It's enabled (I can hit it using GWMI via my account), so it must be a permissions thing for WMI specifically, of some sort.

Comment: Are you running this script as you, or as a different user? If you can connect to WMI on the server, you might need [permissions to the event log](http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/04/30/giving-non-administrators-permission-to-read-event-logs-windows-2003-and-windows-2008.aspx). Though that wouldn't explain why PowerShell works and WMI doesn't. I'm kinda guessing here, what about asking a member of the servers team to run your script and see if it works for them?

Comment: What my servers team wound up doing was adding the credential I'm using to the "Distributed COM users group" to each server, via GPO.  That seems to have fixed it.  Thanks for the help!